# Who Is This Person Walking By The Computer Observer Room?

Tags: plot-explanation, resident-evil

After being separated from the Umbrella Unit in *Resident Evil* (2002), Alice and Matt are taken away. Alice is quarantined in a Raccoon Hospital. Alice woke up in an Empty Quarantine room with a window glass in front of her, She yells and bangs the window glass for help. As the camera moves away, we can see a person walking by.

[image]

Who exactly is this person? During the making of the movie, Anderson doesn't talk about this scene or about the person walking by.

Answer (score 2):

That was [William Birkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Resident_Evil_characters#William_Birkin), who had a major role in video games but in movies, he didn't come back for the sequel.

> In the first Resident Evil film, Birkin makes an uncredited cameo appearance portrayed by Jason Isaacs as the head of the Nemesis project, who was also the film's narrator. According to an audio commentary by Paul W. S. Anderson, Isaacs was planned to reprise this role in the sequel Resident Evil: Apocalypse, but left the project for undisclosed reasons, so an original character named Dr. Alexander Isaacs (played by Iain Glen) was created to fulfill Birkin's role in the sequel.

Comment: That's Great! i never know that was Isaacs in the first one.

Comment: @OwenAyanami he is a friend of the director, so maybe that's why when he didn't come back for the sequel they gave a new character his real name.